# Is there a R option to better illustrate spatial distribution of community types?

Tags: r, visualization, distribution, spatial

I have different type of biological communities within different vertical profiles of a water column. I want to show the distribution of these groups across the vertical profiles taken in three different types of environment.

At the moment, I have tried using geom tiles, which deliver the wanted message, but I am not satisfied with the design. I would like to know if some people have alternatives to make it look better, such as graphs similar to density plots.

```
x=c("A1","A1","A1","B1","B1","B1","C1","C1","C1")
y=factor(c("surface","intermediate","bottom","surface","intermediate","bottom","surface","intermediate","bottom"))
Protists=c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,3,3)
area=factor(c("estuaries","estuaries","estuaries","continental","continental","continental","oceanic","oceanic","oceanic"))
table=data.frame(Profile=x,depth=y,Type=Protists,area=area)
colors.gr=c("1"="#fd8d3c","2"="#993404","3"="#fcae91")
ggplot(table,aes(Profile,depth,width=.9,height=.9))+
  geom_tile(aes(x=factor(Profile),fill=factor(Type)),colour="grey50")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(c("surface","intermediate","bottom")))+
  facet_grid(cols=vars(area),space="free_x",scales="free_x")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors.gr)
```

[image: result from above code]

Any would have suggestions to improve it? An idea i had to do something similar to this link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/one-of-the-best-and-most-underutilized-graphs-in-ggplot2/, but I am not sure how to approach it with discrete values. Thanks!

Comment: Density plots do not make sense for you data: While they do work with categorical data as the link you have shared shows, they reflect relative frequencies. You just have one observation per case - they are all equally frequent.

Comment: Hi yes I understood it, it was more as a visualization idea, if there was something similarly looking. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying that I agree with @shs advice regarding density plots. But decided to tinker with your code alittle to replicate the look of the stacked density plots. I also removed some redundancy in the plot code since you factored *Profile* outside of the ggplot code and did not need to use `scale_y_discrete()`.

```
ggplot(table,aes(Profile,depth,width=1.2))+  # Increased width to promote overlap
  geom_tile(aes(fill=factor(Type)))+
  facet_grid(cols=vars(area), scales = "free_x") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors.gr)+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "lines"))   #Removes spacing between facets
```

[image]
You might consider adding vertical or horizontal lines with `geom_vline()` or `geom_hline()` that are dashed to provide emphasis as needed.